# Getting decimal number input/output for Math.abs

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

So my question is the following: 
I get an error on line 12 that I want to solve but haven't found the result for.
I use Eclipse to run and write my code.

This is what I do:

1. I write absolute
2. I enter a number with decimals
3. an error pops up saying

   ```
   Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
   at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
   at apples.main(apples.java:12)
   ```

How come this does not work? Also, I tried running it in CMD outside of Eclipse aswell, without sucess.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class apples
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Select one of the following(absolute,ceil,floor,max,min,power,squareroot):  ");
      String code = scan.nextLine();
      if (code.contains("absolute"))
      {
         System.out.println("Enter a number to get absolute value: ");
         Scanner num1 = new Scanner(System.in);
         double numberone;
         double numberone1 = num1.nextDouble();
         System.out.println(Math.abs(numberone1));
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working for me if i put valid input input for your program .

If you are getting [InputMismatchException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html) means you are not providing expected input to Scanner.

```
double numberone1 = num1.nextDouble();
```

For this from your command you should give Double value only otherwise it will throw `InputMismatchException`

Comment: Okai, so how can I get it to be able to run numbers like -5, -5.2, -5.23, -5.234 and so on?

Comment: These inputs will work for your code , but any thing except int, long (can be with sign -/+)  like 'String' will not work .

Comment: So why do I get error when I type that in? Refearing to previous answer and comment I added there.

Comment: The default delimiter pattern for Scanner is whitespace: "-5 -5.2 -5.23 -5.234". I tested that with your code modified to add a loop using num1.hasNext. If you need commas, look at Scanner's useDelimiter.

Comment: Thank you mate! You just figured it out and I feel sooo dumb now... I've allways used dots instead of commas...

Answer (score 1):

**InputMismatchException**, this exception thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type.

`num1.nextDouble()` -> Here your passing value does not match the double regular expression, or is out of range.

Comment: So this is what it is supposed to look like? Scanner num1 = new Scanner(System.in);
  double numberone1 = num1.nextDouble();
  System.out.println(Math.abs(numberone1));

Comment: Select one of the following (absolute,ceil,floor,max,min,power,squareroot):  
absolute
Enter a number to get absolute value: 
-24.3

Answer (score -1):

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Test{

    private static Scanner scan;
    private static Scanner num1;
    public static void main(String[] args){

        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String code;
        do{  
        System.out.println("Select one of the following(absolute,ceil,floor,max,min,power,squareroot):  ");
            code = scan.nextLine();
        if (code.contains("absolute"))
          {

             System.out.println("Enter a number to get absolute value: ");
             num1 = new Scanner(System.in);
             //double numberone;
             double numberone1 = num1.nextDouble();
             System.out.println(Math.abs(numberone1));
             }
          }while(!code.contains("absolute"));

    }
}
```